# function parameters should work for string and unicode

Tags: elixir

I am counting number of occurrences in a string by

```
def count(strand,nucleotide) do
Enum.count(String.graphemes(strand),&(&1==List.to_string([nucleotide])))

end
```

It works fine if I pass strand as "AAA" but fails if I pass like 'AAA' i.e a charlist.

gives me

> ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in String.Unicode.graphemes/1

How can I make it work for unicode argument as well

I can do `to_string(strand)` to make it work but as it is a charlist why cant I do  simple as `Enum.count('AAA',&(&1 == 'A'))` it returns me 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing a list to an integer.

```
is_list('A')                                  # true
[65] == 'A'                                   # true
[65, 66] = 'AB'                               # true
[128105, 8205, 128105, 8205, 128103] == '‍‍'  # true
```

You can, for example, do

```
  Enum.count('AAA', fn x ->
    [codepoint] = 'A'
    x == codepoint
  end)
```

Comment: You probably want to match codepoint outside the anonymous function. So you would have something more like this: `Enum.count('AAA', &(&1 == codepoint))` or if the function can take a codepoint something like `Enum.count('AAA', &(&1 == ?A))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use guard clauses to define a clause that handles binaries, and clause that handles charlists. I think it would make more sense to pass the nucleotide as a codepoint rather than a charlist:

```elixir
defmodule CodepointNucleotide do
  def count(strand, nucleotide) when is_binary(strand) do
    count(String.to_charlist(strand), nucleotide)
  end

  def count(strand, nucleotide) when is_list(strand) do
    Enum.count(strand, &(&1 == nucleotide))
  end
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
iex(1)> CodepointNucleotide.count("AAA", ?A)
3
iex(2)> CodepointNucleotide.count("ABA", ?A)
2
iex(3)> CodepointNucleotide.count('AAA', ?A)
3
iex(4)> CodepointNucleotide.count('ABA', ?A)
2
```

You could also make the nucleotide a binary:

```elixir
defmodule BinaryNucleotide do
  def count(strand, nucleotide) when is_binary(strand) do
    strand
    |> String.graphemes()
    |> Enum.count(&(&1 == nucleotide))
  end

  def count(strand, <<nucleotide::utf8>>) when is_list(strand) do
    Enum.count(strand, &(&1 == nucleotide))
  end
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
iex(5)> BinaryNucleotide.count("AAA", "A")
3
iex(6)> BinaryNucleotide.count("ABA", "A")
2
iex(7)> BinaryNucleotide.count('AAA', "A")
3
iex(8)> BinaryNucleotide.count('ABA', "A")
2
```